# Why can't I assign undefined to window.load?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I just noticed this strange effect

```
window.onload = undefined;
console.log(window.onload); // print 'null', instead of 'undefined'
```

While it works as expected for other objects, including built-in, objects, e.g.

```
Array.prototype.slice = undefined;
console.log(Array.prototype.slice); // print 'undefined'
```

Why is that the case?

Comment: Why would you want to assign undefined to window.load?

Comment: No practical reason, I was looking at another SO question and while attempting to answer, I noticed this behavior which didn't work as I expected.

Comment: What browser did you test in? Perhaps its different across multiple browsers.

Comment: You might get some hints in this article: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2011/4/Replacing-setTimeout-Globally I believe it comes close or addresses some similar issues!

Comment: @TJHeuvel Both Chrome and Firefox gave me the same result

Comment: Well 'undefined' is pretty JavaScript-ish, it doesn't mean "this pointer does not reference any memory address" but (more or less) "this pointer/value is not defined". Array.slice CAN be defined or not (even if we don't expect it's not) while onload is created (ok at least in IE) and then defined first time it's called (and it can be null). From code point of view it's the same but it means it'll always EXIST (but it may be empty/null).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is like this because `.onload` is a setter and it works something like this:

```
window = {
    // Other window properties and methods

    get onload() {
        // returns null if no function was added or returns the last function added
    },

    set onload(value) {
        if (typeof value === 'function') {
            loadListener = value; // loadListener is the function called when load event is triggered
        }
    }

    // Other window properties and methods
}
```

Comment: It does explain the phenomenon, but how do you know this?

Comment: this is the logic of the event driven architecture, you can use multiple `.onload` function assignments and all of them will work, read more on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming or on my blog: http://justsimplejs.blogspot.com/2012/07/event-driven-programming.html , where I created my own event emitter based on nodejs's eventEmitter class, it is different from this `.onevent` syntax, but it works in the same way

Comment: You cannot use multiple onload function if you do not handle that logic by yourself (or if you do not use a library that does that for you).

Comment: Yes you're right, I haven't used `.onevent` syntax for ages, I always use `.addEventListener()` method, that's why I confused its functional

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  I thought getter and setter are relatively new stuff and window object couldn't be implemented without them (unless it's not implemented in JS of course). I guess they retrofitted the code and assumed it was backward compatible given typical use cases of onload.  BTW, do you know a place where I can look at the source code of built-in objects like window?  I tried to search Chromium but couldn't find code for built-in JS objects in there.

Comment: After some digging, I found the WebKit code for window, it's implemented as a native object; while the semantic is similar to what you describe, your code isn't really how it's implemented (at least for WebKit). http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/page/DOMWindow.cpp&exact_package=chromium&q=domwindow&ct=rc&cd=2&sq=